# How to edit style of CU3ER captions in Wordpress?

Tags: css, wordpress, stylesheet

May i know how could i edit the style of description of the images in CU3ER of wordpress ?
i find several places but still no way to edit or is it possible to edit through the physical file code directly ?

Link of website: http://jprivateyes.com/

The way to insert image is to add feature image for the pages
[image]

This is the image and i want to edit the style of text of the image...
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use official CU3ER plugin - wpCU3ER... You can get it for free at Wordpress plugins directory or from https://getcu3er.com/account/plugins